# How to get the Bottle size (number of elements) in YARP?

Tags: yarp

I'm wondering if there is a way to get the size (number of elements) of a Bottle in YARP. Maybe there is a function/method to do that. I searched a solution online, but without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`yarp::os::Bottle::size()`](https://yarp.it/git-master/classyarp_1_1os_1_1Bottle.html#a4d2e210ab875bff598973ab0a6919c31).